# load a world asynchronously or without blocking the main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, bukkit

I'm working on a minigames plugin. After an arena finishes it should be regenerated - I use the unload and load trick. It has an obvious disadvantage - it freezes the server for a while to prepare spawn areas. I decided to put the arena reset code into an runnable asynchronous task `runTaskAsynchronously()`. However, when the server tries to run the code inside the thread, it throws an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Asynchronous entity world add!
```

Here's a part of my code:

```
getServer().getScheduler().runTaskAsynchronously(this, new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        String w_name = world.getName();
        getServer().unloadWorld(world.getName(), false);
        world = getServer().createWorld(new WorldCreator(w_name));
    }
});
```

Any suggestions how to deal with this problem?

Comment: You've posted an exception, but it doesn't really give us a full picture as to what your question/problem is

Comment: Looks like the minigames framework doesn't want you resetting the arena in another thread, probably because it doesn't handle that properly.

Comment: According to the Bukkit scheduler programming wiki, asynchronous tasks should never access any API in Bukkit.

Answer (score 1):

Bukkit doesn't like it when you try to edit anything through the API in an async task. Reading and processing is fine but bukkit enforces nothing when it comes to thread safety and thus affecting the world with more than 1 thread can cause issues.

Try splitting up your arena reset into smaller chunks and spreading out the operation over several ticks with a series of synchronous tasks, might help with the performance.

This isn't my code but it does a decent job of demonstrating the idea https://gist.github.com/aadnk/5443172

Answer (score 0):

**-- You can load worlds async using this: http://pastebin.com/K9CuVMS5 --**

No you cannot, and if you tried it would have a high chance of world corruption. But if you don't care about it this is what you can do:
Bukkit loads worlds via `Bukkit.createWorld(WorldCreator)` which activates `Server.createWorld(WorldCreator)` which activates:

```
Validate.notNull(creator, "Creator may not be null");
    String name = creator.name();
    ChunkGenerator generator = creator.generator();
    File folder = new File(this.getWorldContainer(), name);
    World world = this.getWorld(name);
    WorldType type = WorldType.getType(creator.type().getName());
    boolean generateStructures = creator.generateStructures();
    if(world != null) {
        return world;
    } else if(folder.exists() && !folder.isDirectory()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("File exists with the name \'" + name + "\' and isn\'t a folder");
    } else {
        if(generator == null) {
            generator = this.getGenerator(name);
        }

        WorldLoaderServer converter = new WorldLoaderServer(this.getWorldContainer());
        if(converter.isConvertable(name)) {
            this.getLogger().info("Converting world \'" + name + "\'");
            converter.convert(name, new ConvertProgressUpdater(this.console));
        }

        int dimension = 10 + this.console.worlds.size();
        boolean used = false;

        do {
            Iterator sdm = this.console.worlds.iterator();

            while(sdm.hasNext()) {
                WorldServer hardcore = (WorldServer)sdm.next();
                used = hardcore.dimension == dimension;
                if(used) {
                    ++dimension;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while(used);

        boolean var25 = false;
        ServerNBTManager var24 = new ServerNBTManager(this.getWorldContainer(), name, true);
        WorldData worlddata = var24.getWorldData();
        if(worlddata == null) {
            WorldSettings internal = new WorldSettings(creator.seed(), EnumGamemode.getById(this.getDefaultGameMode().getValue()), generateStructures, var25, type);
            internal.setGeneratorSettings(creator.generatorSettings());
            worlddata = new WorldData(internal, name);
        }

        worlddata.checkName(name);
        WorldServer var26 = (WorldServer)(new WorldServer(this.console, var24, worlddata, dimension, this.console.methodProfiler, creator.environment(), generator)).b();
        if(!this.worlds.containsKey(name.toLowerCase())) {
            return null;
        } else {
            var26.scoreboard = this.getScoreboardManager().getMainScoreboard().getHandle();
            var26.tracker = new EntityTracker(var26);
            var26.addIWorldAccess(new WorldManager(this.console, var26));
            var26.worldData.setDifficulty(EnumDifficulty.EASY);
            var26.setSpawnFlags(true, true);
            this.console.worlds.add(var26);
            if(generator != null) {
                var26.getWorld().getPopulators().addAll(generator.getDefaultPopulators(var26.getWorld()));
            }

            this.pluginManager.callEvent(new WorldInitEvent(var26.getWorld()));
            System.out.print("Preparing start region for level " + (this.console.worlds.size() - 1) + " (Seed: " + var26.getSeed() + ")");
            if(var26.getWorld().getKeepSpawnInMemory()) {
                short short1 = 196;
                long i = System.currentTimeMillis();

                for(int j = -short1; j <= short1; j += 16) {
                    for(int k = -short1; k <= short1; k += 16) {
                        long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        if(l < i) {
                            i = l;
                        }

                        if(l > i + 1000L) {
                            int chunkcoordinates = (short1 * 2 + 1) * (short1 * 2 + 1);
                            int j1 = (j + short1) * (short1 * 2 + 1) + k + 1;
                            System.out.println("Preparing spawn area for " + name + ", " + j1 * 100 / chunkcoordinates + "%");
                            i = l;
                        }

                        BlockPosition var27 = var26.getSpawn();
                        var26.chunkProviderServer.getChunkAt(var27.getX() + j >> 4, var27.getZ() + k >> 4);
                    }
                }
            }

            this.pluginManager.callEvent(new WorldLoadEvent(var26.getWorld()));
            return var26.getWorld();
        }
    }
```

Now by creating you own world loader, you can make it so it only generates a chunk every tick or so.